# Trying to remove an DOM table using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a program that creates a table every time I press a button.

The page keeps creating duplicate tables on click.

I am trying to delete/remove/replace the table if it exists but it doesn't do anything.

I have tried the following code

```
document.getElementById("paragraphDOM").outerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("paragraphDOM").remove();
            document.getElementById("paragraphDOM").removeChild(tbl);
            document.getElementById("paragraphDOM").blur;
            document.getElementById("paragraphDOM").innerHTML = "";
```

None of these gets rid of the original table, I even tried creating a paragraph and adding the table to it and then removing it as I got an error trying to set outer html to "" that it needed a parent.

Comment: Check the return of getElementById before using it, it may not be valid.

Comment: What is the if of your table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MSIE you have to reference the table's parent to be able to remove the node:

```
let table = document.getElementById('#mytable');
let parent = table.parentNode;
parentNode.removeChild(table);
```

otherwise in all other current browsers you should be able to just use [`.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove):

```
let table = document.getElementById('#mytable');
table.remove();
```

See also [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=childnode-remove) for more detailed browser support information.

Comment: I created the following page

Comment: The js for what you gave me is https://jsfiddle.net/rvermaak/2qp01wno/3/

But my page https://jsfiddle.net/rvermaak/humnoejL/3/

Keeps creating more tables

I know it has to be something stupid I'm doing , but I can't see it.

Comment: @Robert your fiddle doesn't work, and it's far too long for me to bother debugging.   please create a small self contained example with the bare minimum of code that demonstrates the issue.   Chances are you'll spot what you've done wrong then anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Just use parentNode to define the parent of table then apply removeChild() on it

```
var tbl=document.getElementById("paragraphDOM");
if(tbl) tbl.parentNode.removeChild(tbl);
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your variable `tbl` is correctly defined as the table you want to remove, this will remove it:

```
tbl.parentNode.removeChild(tbl);
```

If you already have the new table ready to replace `tbl`, let's call it `newTbl` here, you can simply do this:

```
tbl.parentNode.replaceChild(newTbl,tbl);
```